# AWS authentication issue while using deployment script

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, deployment

From today only I started getting issue while running deployment scripts from my local VM. I am not sure if it's a known issue or some setup related thing which is missing on my VM .

> - Authentication failed while running deploy_one_off:
>
> [vvaibhav@gld2vm40 debesys (topic/Add_FIX_IBDC_Session_Subtype_info_to_pub-DEB-107734)]$ /opt/virtualenv/devws/bin/python2 deploy/chef/scripts/deploy_one_off.py -s gla2vm178 --email vagesh.vaibhav@trade.tt -c dropcopyclientnode -r 5fff2fe00e5082b39fd5a978af7bf38770a95ef9 --request-build --run-chef --override-oneoff
>
> Enter your INTAD username:vvaibhav
>
> Enter password for INTAD user vvaibhav:
>
> Checking if dropcopyclientnode cookbook has a build target...DONE
>
> Oops: Failed to authenticate and retrieve AWS Keys from AWS, the package check will
>
> fail.  It is safe to try re-running, but if the problem persists please notify
>
> Deployment and/or ELS.  Exception:

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI,

This issue was resolved as I worked with Tom today morning. It seems that some aws-keys file became stale and we had to delete those files.

$ ls -ltr ~/.aws-keys*

-rw-r--r-- 1 vvaibhav sysadmins 0 Jan  7 07:42 /home/vvaibhav/.aws-keys_deb_read

Comment: Please edit your original answer with this information